# How to write a method in vfpage controller to call different different vfpages for different rec types

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have an object called Industry__c. It has 3 recordtypes Shipping, Sales and Marketing. I have created 3 VFPages. ShippingVFPage, SalesVFPage and MarketingVFPage.

Shipping VFPage:

```
<apex:page controller="Diffrectypes">
<apex:pageBlock title="VFPage1">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="VFPageSection1">
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

MarketingVFPage

```
<apex:page controller="Diffrectypes">
<apex:pageBlock title="VFPage1">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="VFPageSection1">
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

SalesVFPage

```
<apex:page controller="Diffrectypes">
<apex:pageBlock title="VFPage1">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="VFPageSection1">
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I want to create a controller with a method to call vfpage based on recordtype but I am not sure how to do it. how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want a fourth page to control that logic. I see two general ideas of how you might decide to do it.

## Option 1: Redirect

```
<apex:page controller="Diffrectypes" action="{!redirect}">
    Default message when no record type is found...
</apex:page>
```

The redirect would be something like this:

```
public PageReference redirect() {
    PageReference ref;
    SObject record = loadRecord(); // However you choose to do this part
    Id recordTypeId = (Id)record.get('RecordTypeId');
    String recordTypeName = record.getSObjectType().getDescribe()
       .getRecordTypeInfosById().get(recordTypeId).getName();
    if(recordTypeName == 'record type 1') {
        ref = Page.shipping;
    } else if(recordTypeName == 'record type 2') {
        ref = Page.Marketing;
    } else if(recordTypeName == 'record type 3') {
        ref = Page.Sales;
    }
    if(ref != null) {
        ref.getParameters().putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
    }
    return ref;
}
```

## Option 2: Include

```
<apex:page controller="Diffrectypes">
    <apex:include pageName="{!pageName}" />
</apex:page>
```

This works generally the same way, except you return a string with the page name:

```
public String getPageName() {
    String pageName = 'pagenotfound'; // default
    SObject record = loadRecord(); // However you choose to do this part
    Id recordTypeId = (Id)record.get('RecordTypeId');
    String recordTypeName = record.getSObjectType().getDescribe()
       .getRecordTypeInfosById().get(recordTypeId).getName();
    if(recordTypeName == 'record type 1') {
        pageName = 'shipping';
    } else if(recordTypeName == 'record type 2') {
        pageName = 'Marketing';
    } else if(recordTypeName == 'record type 3') {
        pageName = 'Sales';
    }
    return pageName;
}
```

Either way, you might also use a Custom Metadata or Custom Setting to control the logic instead of embedded if-else statements, but if you don't really plan on expanding this much larger, this design would work fine.

Comment: Hi Fox, Thank you for above code. I choose to go with second option. Can you tell me what is the below line exactly doing.  SObject record = loadRecord();

Comment: @Harvey It's just a placeholder for whatever you might do to load your record. You're not using a StandardController, so I just kind of presumed that you're reading a page parameter or something. If you're working with a concrete SObject, like Account or MyObject__c, you can replace SObject with that data type instead. This code is meant to show an example in a generic manner.

Comment: Thank you very much Fox. The second option worked for me.